# I can't stop the css/jquery animation on focus

Tags: jquery, css, hover, focus

I want to stop the animation of the span on focus of the input.

When I doing hover, there is no problem, always good. But I want to stop span when I focus input. The problems are here. My code are [here](http://codepen.io/ardazaman/pen/qNPjgL).

Actualy I want to do this with css not scss. [here](http://codepen.io/see8ch/pen/KpLrd)

And Html :

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<section id="text">
  <p><span> İSİM</span><input name="name" type="text" placeholder="İsminiz" /></p>

  <p><span> KONU </span><input name="subject" type="text"  placeholder="Konu"/></p>

  <p><span> MAİL </span><input name="mail" type="email"  placeholder="Mailiniz"/></p>

  <p><span> MESAJ </span><textarea name="message" type="text" placeholder="Mesajınız"></textarea>

 </section>
```

CSS:

```
  .aktif1{width:100px;transition:1s;}
.aktif2{width:450px;transition:1s;}

body{
  background:#f7f7f7;
}

p{
  position: relative;
  width:450px;
}

section#text{
  position:relative;
  margin-left:500px;
  margin-top:150px;
}

p input{
  outline:none;
  width:330px;
  height:40px;
  padding-left:120px;
}

p textarea{
  outline:none;
  max-width:330px;
  max-height:40px;
  width:330px;
  height:40px;
  padding-left:120px;
}


p span{
  width:455px;
  height:45px;
  background:#333;
  position: absolute;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:50px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  transition:1s;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
  fonk1();
  $('section#text input').focus(function(){
    fonk1().stop();
  });

    fonk2();
  $('section#text input').blur(function(){
     fonk2();
  });
});


var fonk1 = function(){
  $('section#text p').mouseenter(function(){
      $('span',this).animate(1000,function(){
          $(this).css({'width':'100'});
      });
  });
}

var fonk2 = function(){
  $('section#text p').mouseleave(function(){
    $('span',this).animate(1000,function(){
          $(this).css({'width':'450'});
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: If you want the same for the first codepen just **view the compiled CSS** ... on the css window click the down arrow and select view compiled CSS. Then you can see it as plain CSS

Comment: Thank you I didn't know this feature. But I just wonder where I am doing error in my code.

Comment: Do you want to 'stop the animation as soon as the user focuses the input'? Did you mean that with 'stop span' / 'stop hover'?

Comment: yes I try to say that.

Comment: You mix css animations and jquery animations, maybe that is part of your problem? And you should call .stop() or .finish() like $('span',this).finish();, not on the result of the fonk function that does not return anything :-)

Answer (score 2):

**I played a lot with this script.**

Had so much fun that I almost forgot about your question! .oO(LOL)

I went *way much further* than it's scope...
So this answer is my trial to redo my changes step by step.

**----- Step 1**
Here is [the basics I first changed](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/1umkn970/)...
That may be enought to answer to the animation bug you have.
I removed a lot from your script here.
Like said in comments, you are mixing `.animate()` ans `.css()`...
And I don't get why you create a function to call a function in this case.
You are confusing on which event to call, maybe...
So I cleaned it.

**----- Step 2**
But then... *«I want to stop span when I focus input»*
**Which I suppose to be the real question here**:

I think I went a bit further here.... Understanding it as you want the `span` to stay put on the left when the field is not empty... No matter if the field is focussed or not.
[That's exactly what I've done next!](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/6asmfvj3/) ;)

I've wrapped your mouseleave script with a condition:

```
if( $(this).children("input").val() == "" ){
```

**----- Step 3**
And, just to thank you for my actual REAL fun (!)...
[Here is where I am now](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/rgLwm9fL/) with this script.

This REALLY makes a nice input forms !
Again, thank you, you made my day!

**----- Step 4**
*Future!*
It will be to add input validation before adding a checkmark to the `span`.
Would have to a a red X if "non-conform".
But I stop here for now.
;)